# Getting the value of a function to echo in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to this, so please forgive me in advance.  I am trying to get the value from this function below that resides inside a .JS file to return/print the value in PHP

### FUNCTION

```
$("#blah").yeahblah({
    flat: true,
    change: function(color) {
        var hsv = color.toHsv();
        var rgb = color.toRgbString();
        var hex = color.toHexString();
        //console.log("callback",color.toHslString(), color.toHsl().h, color.toHsl().s, color.toHsl().l)
        $("#docs-content").css({
            'background-color': color.toRgbString()
        }).toggleClass("dark", hsv.v < .5);
        $("#switch-current-rgb").text(rgb);
        $("#switch-current-hex").text(hex);
    },
    show: function() {

    },
    hide: function() {

    },
    showInput: true,
    showPalette: true,
    palette: ['white', '#306', '#c5c88d', '#ac5c5c', '#344660']
});
```

---

### PHP Code

```
<?php $rgbcolor=$("#blah").yeahblah; ?>
```

---

### Expected Return

RGB(201,102,0)

====================

Any directions on how I can get the value would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Can't do it this way as the PHP compiler has already run.

Comment: PHP runs on the server when the page is being created. Javascript runs on the client after PHP has sent it.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. JavaScript runs on the browser. They don't operate alongside each other. Communication between the two is generally facilitated via ajax.

Comment: I always find it amazing how often this exact question comes up. JS runs in the browser, PHP on the server. You can do PHP -> JS easily but the reverse requires a new HTTP request. Usually done over AJAX.

Comment: I solved the issue by taking your advice about using AJAX - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm